# LibGDX autoscale text in Label

Tags: java, libgdx, label

in my libgdx project I have a label that displays a  number wich will be bigger. 
But when the number gets too big, its bigger than the label.
How can I do it that the size of the text gets smaller when the text is bigger than the label, so that it isn't too  big an more?

Comment: So, did you try my solution ? Did that work ? If no, what did you observe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried it, but if you look to the [Label documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html), there is a [setFontScale method](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html#setFontScale-float-).

Did you try it ?

The width of the label is given by `yourLabel.getPrefWidth()` and the width of the text inside the label is given by `yourLabel.getGlyphLayout.width`. You could compare the both, and scale down the font if the width of the text is bigger thant the width of the label.

I guess you could use something like this in your `render()` :

```
if(yourLabel.getGlyphLayout.width > yourLabel.getPrefWidth()){
    yourLabel.setFontScale(yourLabel.getPrefWidth()/yourLabel.getGlyphLayout.width);
}
```